# Bundle is null at onCreate method altho I saved it at onSaveInstanceState method after init post on twitter

Tags: android

I   have a proble of saving bundle of actovuty when I start twitter web view in order to poat data on twitter from my activity.

Akthi I save the Bundle  data at onSaveInstanceState after the twitter (web view) is finished the bundle is null at on create of the caller to tiwtter activity.

here is the the code :

```
 CallerActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString (Utils.CREATE_JSON_STRING_BUNDLE_KEY, mJsonString);
        outState.putInt (UIhelper.UI_BASIC_TYPE_BUNDLE_KEY, mUiCurrentBasicType);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put `super.onSaveInstanceState()` in the end of the `onSaveInstanceState` function and implement `onRestoreInstanceState` in which you get your data back